# Rendering angular component from the markdown file

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have markdown file where I did use normal HTML tags, but also I wanted to use angular component selector, but without success. In case of the angularjs I could use compile function to do it, but in the newer angular it looks like this process is much more complex. Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-haze-vz1m5)

I wanted to recreate process of how angular team is doing their guide page. Especially angular material lib. Guide is written in the markdown, but I don't how they are able to embed their example components in those pages. Components added by the selector in the markdown file won't be rendered.

Comment: Take a look at the source code of Angular Material: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/tools/markdown-to-html/transform-markdown.ts

Comment: @Roy thank you for point me this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution resides in **Angular Elements**.
Using Angular Elements you will be able to use any angular component as a normal HTML component. And to your surprise, this is the exact same approach Angular team uses for their documentations as well. eg you have an component like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  templateUrl: './my-comp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-comp.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComp{
  @Input() message = '';
}
```

you can use the component just like a built-in HTML element in content that you add directly into the DOM:

```
<my-comp message="hello"></my-comp>
```

Have a look at the Angular's official Docs for Angular Elements [**here**](https://angular.io/guide/elements)

Comment: Thank you! This answer solved my problems.

Comment: dev_ob I am able to pass primitive types as input but when tried to pass object or array, its not working. cc: @Dawid